# Javascript, convert date to different format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this date `2015/08/06 06:00` and i want to convert it to `6th August 2015 at 6am`.  I know how to do this in php but having trouble with jquery.

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
    var d = new Date('2015/08/06 06:00');
    var d_formatted = d.getDate() + '/' +  monthNames[d.getMonth()] '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

How do i get the date suffix and the time?

Comment: Libraries such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) can do this for you.

Comment: thanks @ThiefMaster got it working with moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, i have Fiddled your needs http://jsfiddle.net/j6tb81qy/

```
function DateFormat(arg)
{
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  var Dates;
  if(arg.getDate()==1)
    Dates =arg.getDate() + 'st';
  if(arg.getDate()==2)
    Dates =arg.getDate() + 'nd';
  if(arg.getDate()== 3)
     Dates =arg.getDate() + ' rd';
  if(arg.getDate()> 3)
  Dates = arg.getDate() +'th'

  var hours ='';
  console.log(Dates)
  hours = arg.getHours();
  if(arg.getHours() >12)
  {
    hours = (arg.getHours() %12)+ ' PM'
  }
  else          
  {
    hours =arg.getHours()+ ' AM'
  }

  Dates = Dates + ' ' + monthNames[arg.getMonth()] +' ' + arg.getFullYear().toString() + ' at ' + hours.toString();
  return Dates; 
}

var d = new Date();
var val= DateFormat(d);
alert(val);

//6th August 2015 at 6am
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use moment.js to do this

```
$(function () {
  $('.date').each(function (index, dateElem) {
    var $dateElem = $(dateElem);
    var formatted = moment($dateElem.text(), 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMMM D');
    $dateElem.text(formatted);
   })
 });​
```

Comment: I use moment.js a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toString();
```

The result of n will be:

```
Thu Aug 06 2015 12:52:33 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp

Comment: how do i remove the `GMT-0300 (BRT)`?

Comment: Use slice function.     `n.slice(0,-15)`

Answer (score 0):

With `Date` object, there are couple of methods to retrieve time:-

- `getHours()` and `getUTCHours()`
- `getMinutes()` and `getUTCMinutes()`
- `getSeconds()` and `getUTCSeconds()`
- `getMilliseconds()` and `getUTCMilliseconds()`

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods